# Can I bring non-prescribed medication to South Korea?

Tags: luggage, health, south-korea

When travelling, I like to bring a few non-prescribed medications with me just in case I ever need them, such as aspirin/paracetamol/ibuprofen, diarrhoea/sickness tablets, and sleeping tablets.

I will be going to South Korea soon and wanted to double-check that these are okay to bring with me. I had a look at sources such as https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/south-korea, and from what I can tell it is okay to bring some medications. However, I could not see any specific examples of medications.

Will I be okay to take these with me? And, if it is okay, are there any restrictions e.g. only kept in carry-on luggage?

Comment: You don't name the actual meds. What is OTC in South Korea (over the counter, i.e., non-prescription) and what isn't OTC may be different than what you're used to.